# Vuejs Bind value to v-model from prop or computed value

Tags: vue.js, binding, vuejs2, components

I have an input that is a component and rendered in the master view as so:

```html
<slug v-model="slug"></slug>
```

Then I have a component view such as below:

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field box label="Slug*" v-model="slug" @change="strtoslug"  :rules="requiredRule"></v-text-field>
</template>
```

I am running a computed method to get and set the data and can `console.log` with no issues. In the editing state, I can't populate `v-model` with an updated computed state, as I cant declare as a data source upon render.

Here is my whole code block:

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field box label="Slug*" v-model="slug" @change="strtoslug"  :rules="requiredRule"></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
//Set the params
export default {
  name:'slug',
  props: ['value'],
  //Set the data
  data() {
      const self = this;
      return {
          slugstr: '',
          requiredRule: [
              (v) => !!v || 'Field is required',
          ],
        }
    },
    watch: {
    },
    //Get the value onchange computer to return from component
    computed: {
        slug: {
          get() {
              return this.value;
          },
          set(val) {
            //set the slug
            this.slugstr = val;
            this.slug    = val;
            //send data back to parent
            this.$emit('input',val)
             return this.value;
          }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
      const self = this;
      //Set the templates get request
     },
      methods: {
        strtoslug: function(value){
            this.slug = this.sanitizeSlug(value);
        },

        sanitizeSlug: function(title) {
         var slug = "";
         // Change to lower case
         var titleLower = title.toLowerCase();
         // Letter "e"
         slug = titleLower.replace(/e|é|è|ẽ|ẻ|ẹ|ê|ế|ề|ễ|ể|ệ/gi, 'e');
         // Letter "a"
         slug = slug.replace(/a|á|à|ã|ả|ạ|ă|ắ|ằ|ẵ|ẳ|ặ|â|ấ|ầ|ẫ|ẩ|ậ/gi, 'a');
         // Letter "o"
         slug = slug.replace(/o|ó|ò|õ|ỏ|ọ|ô|ố|ồ|ỗ|ổ|ộ|ơ|ớ|ờ|ỡ|ở|ợ/gi, 'o');
         // Letter "u"
         slug = slug.replace(/u|ú|ù|ũ|ủ|ụ|ư|ứ|ừ|ữ|ử|ự/gi, 'u');
         // Letter "d"
         slug = slug.replace(/đ/gi, 'd');
         // Trim the last whitespace
         slug = slug.replace(/\s*$/g, '');
         // Remove Punctuation
         slug = slug.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\`~()]/g,"");
         // Change whitespace to "-"
         slug = slug.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
     //Return the formatted str
     return slug;
   }
 }

}
</script>
```

The `onchange` happens in the `console.log`, but I just cannot get it to render inside the `input` as a value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your computed property has an infinite loop because its setter sets itself again:

```js
computed: {
  slug: {
    set(val) {
      this.slug = val; // <-- sets itself again -- infinite loop
      this.$emit('input', val);
    }
  }
},
```

That infinite loop prevents your component from emitting the value to the parent, and you should see a console error similar to: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

But it looks like you actually want the emitted value to be sanitized with `sanitizeSlug()` beforehand. Currently, it emits the raw input value on each input (e.g., each keypress), and then emits a sanitized value with the `change`-event, which occurs after the `<v-text-field>` loses focus. The `change`-event handler is redundant, given you already have `v-model="slug"`, so it could be removed. Also, it's probably better to sanitize all input values before emitting them.

To fix the problem:

1. In the `slug`'s setter, remove `this.slug = val`, and sanitize the `input` value before emitting it:

   ```js
   computed: {
     slug: {
       set(val) {
         // this.slug = val; // <-- delete this
         this.$emit('input', this.sanitizeSlug(val)); // <-- sanitized input value
       }
     }
   },
   ```
2. Remove the `change`-event handler binding:

   ```html
   <v-text-field box label="Slug*" v-model="slug"
                 <!-- @change="strtoslug" DELETE THIS BINDING -->
                 :rules="requiredRule"></v-text-field>
   ```
3. Also remove the event handler's associated method:

   ```js
   methods: {
     /* strtoslug: function(value){
         this.slug = this.sanitizeSlug(value);
     },*/ // DELETE THIS METHOD
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/Bvaygj?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure I understood well what you're trying to achieve but here are some elements to solve your issue.

I guess you want your parent component to be reactive on a child component property and the child property to be updated by the parent. Tell me if I'm wrong.

This issue may be due to your `return` value in the setter function.
Here are some code with `v-model` used with a custom component.

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <slug v-model="input_data"></slug>
</template>
<script>
import slug from "./components/slug";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      input_data: "hello"
    };
  },
  components: {
    slug
  },
  watch: {
    input_data() {
      console.log("Parent: " + this.input_data);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**slug.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="msg" />
    <p>{{ value }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "slug",
  props: ["value"],
  computed: {
    msg: {
      get: function() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        this.$emit("input", val);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```